# Unable to move Arc in a canvas using JS

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am trying to move the arcs along the x-axis, but it's giving an error that x is not defined in the update function. Are the variables not properly placed or some reference is missing??

Code

```
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
<script>
    var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var c = myCanvas.getContext("2d");

    var redArc = new Circle(50, 60, 10, "red");
    var greenArc = new Circle(80, 60, 15, "green");
    var blueArc = new Circle(120, 60, 20, "blue");

    function Circle(x, y, radius, color) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.color = color;

        this.draw = function() {
            c.beginPath();
            c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
            c.fillStyle = this.color;
            c.fill();
        }

        this.update = function() {
            redArc.x += 1;
            greenArc.x += 1;
            blueArc.x += 1;
            this.draw();
        }
        this.update();
    }        



    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        c.clearRect(0, 0, myCanvas.clientWidth, myCanvas.clientHeight);
        redArc.update();
        greenArc.update();
        blueArc.update();
    }

    animate();
```

How do I go about fixing it? Any suggestions 
Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your **`update`** method with the following :

```
this.update = function() {
   this.x += 1;
   this.draw();
}
```

you should be using `this.x` , **not** the variable names.

```js
var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var c = myCanvas.getContext("2d");

var redArc = new Circle(50, 60, 10, "red");
var greenArc = new Circle(80, 60, 15, "green");
var blueArc = new Circle(120, 60, 20, "blue");

function Circle(x, y, radius, color) {
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
   this.radius = radius;
   this.color = color;

   this.draw = function() {
      c.beginPath();
      c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      c.fillStyle = this.color;
      c.fill();
   }

   this.update = function() {
      this.x += 1;
      this.draw();
   }

   this.update();
}

function animate() {
   c.clearRect(0, 0, myCanvas.clientWidth, myCanvas.clientHeight);
   redArc.update();
   greenArc.update();
   blueArc.update();
   requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

animate();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Ok.. thanks.. that worked, but referring the variables and this.x isn't the same thing? does it makes a difference if i set the increment on this.x or on the variables x position?

Comment: You can not use objects before creating it.